# What's the least common element in the universe?

Tags: physical-organic-chemistry

What's the least common element in the universe? And what is its frequency measured in Hertz?

Comment: What do you mean by frequency?

Comment: Any element above 118, oganesson, in the periodic table. It's frequency is zero Hz, since it isn't here, yet. *And there may be many others that haven' been discahvahd.* (T, Lehrer)

Comment: Probably astatine.

Comment: Questions without elaboration effort are not very welcome, and may be closed. Always think about and search for possible answers thoroughly before posting a question.
Written effort attracts elaborated answers. 

Include in the question what you already know/thought about, what you found in textbook or online resources, what you have understood or not/tried/failed. 

Always add eventually relevant  circumstances and background to prevent wrong assumptions and requests for clarifications.

Comment: There are 2 elements in universe that are so rare they have not been observed in the Universe yet. Which of them is less common ?

Comment: If the question is raised in context of your other question about Ca+ and Fe+ frequences, the mentioned frequencies are frequencies of *molecular* transitions.  Single atoms or ions do not have such frequencies.

Comment: Excluding the artificial ones, I've been often told that the less abundant element in the universe is Astatine.

Comment: Uhhh.. who closed this question and why?  It's a good one.

Answer (score 3):

(edited based on @JonCuster's comment) The rarest known elements are most probably the man-made heavy elements. These isotopes (elements) are very unstable. They most probably also formed in supernovas, but their natural formation is minimal, and due to their short lifetime, they do not accumulate either.

As Jon added, most probably heavier elements are also formed in supernovas, however, I am not aware of any of them observed. The reason for that is 1) again, short lifetime prevents any large accumulation, 2) under the formation conditions they are not atoms, but bare nuclei /plasma, so one cannot observe their atomic spectrum.

Comment: One might suspect there are a number we haven’t made, needing supernova conditions to appear even briefly...

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, I guess. Why do not you make it an answer?

Comment: I'd just add it to your answer - as additional info around the 'formation in stars is minimal' and call it good.